# Ebean: Bean is not enhanced Error

Tags: java, ebean

I am new to Ebean and want to make an easy setup with Spring 4, Ebean 4.5.5, running on Wildfly 8.

Currently there is one Class org.test.models.User, which has Annotations `@Entity` and `@Table(name="user")`.

My ebean.properties look as follows:

```
ebean.classes=org.test.models.User

ebean.debug.sql=true  
ebean.debug.lazyload=false  
ebean.logging=all  

ebean.logging.logfilesharing=all  

ebean.logging.directory=${catalina.base}/logs/trans  

ebean.logging.iud=sql  
ebean.logging.query=sql  
ebean.logging.sqlquery=sql  

ebean.logging.txnCommit=none  

datasource.default=mysql

datasource.mysql.username=ebeanuser  
datasource.mysql.password=123456
datasource.mysql.databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebeantest
datasource.mysql.databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
datasource.mysql.minConnections=1  
datasource.mysql.maxConnections=25  
#datasource.mysql.heartbeatsql=select 1  
datasource.mysql.isolationlevel=read_committed  

ebean.ddl.generate=true  
ebean.ddl.run=true
```

I know that I need enhancing for entities and thus have included the mavenenhancer plugin:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.avaje.ebeanorm</groupId>
 <artifactId>avaje-ebeanorm-mavenenhancer</artifactId>
 <version>4.5.2</version>
 <executions>
 <execution>
 <id>main</id>
 <phase>process-classes</phase>
 <goals>
 <goal>enhance</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
 <packages>org.test.**</packages>
 <transformArgs>debug=9</transformArgs>
 <classpath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classpath>
 <classSource>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classSource>
 <classDestination>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classDestination>
 </configuration>
 </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

When calling `Ebean.save(user)` I get the exception:

```
22:47:27,401 ERROR [com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager] (default task-2) Error in deployment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class org.test.models.User is not enhanced?
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented the plugin in the wrong location (inside the the `<pluginManagement>` tag). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996507/how-do-i-enable-ebean-enhancement-in-maven/15773712#15773712) I arranged my plugins like this:

```
<plugins>
   <!-- mavenenhancer plugin here -->
</plugins>
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
       <!-- lifecycle-mapping to ensure, eclipse runs mavenenhancer only if needed -->
   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```